# ES6 in Rails 5 and compiliing assets on a server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ecmascript-6, capistrano

In my rails 5 application when I'm compiling assets I have exceptions `ExecJS::RuntimeError::SyntaxError .....` I'm using ES6: let, const, `() =>` syntax. I've heard that it's not allowed to just start using it. Is that so? Then how to get it to work well?

Note that locally it all works, only a server it fails when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for the above error.Just replaced the above format with defining function in the argument itself as:

```
[2,3].reduce(function(a,b){ return a +b }, 0)
```